# OVH new IPv4 address

Tags: linux, networking, ip, network-interface

I have an OVH dedicated server (under Debian 10) with the main IP "149.xxx.xxx.xxx".

I bought a Fail-Over IP and I want the server to take into account this new IP, "58.xxx.xxx.xxx". 
Even after following [this guide](https://docs.ovh.com/fr/dedicated/network-ipaliasing/), it is impossible to ping the new IP from outside, even without any firewall.

My interface configuration is the following:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp1s0f0
iface enp1s0f0 inet dhcp

post-up /sbin/ifconfig enp1s0f0:0 58.xxx.xxx.xxx netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast 58.xxx.xxx.xxx
pre-down /sbin/ifconfig enp1s0f0:0 down
```

No errors after `systemctl restart networking`, but no ping either.

Comment: Did you buy the Fail-Over IP from your OVH provider? If so, why is it `58.*` and not `149.*`? Does your OVH provider know that this new IP belongs to your server?

Comment: It’s 2022. You should not be using `ifconfig` anymore on Linux, even if some guides say that. Check the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#iproute2_method) on this topic.

Comment: @harrymc, yes I did. OVH have many IP prefixes, including these two

Comment: @DanielB Thank you, I'll take a look.

Comment: You should perhaps ask OVH Support.

Comment: @harrymc That's what I'm going to do, I'll post the answer once I got it.

Comment: Just sad that OVH provides instructions using `ifconfig` + fake alias instead of `ip address`. But anyway what they provide should work. So to double check you should provide back in the question the whole resulting "low level" network configuration: `ip link; ip -br address; ip route; ip neigh` . Feel free to obfuscate as long as the result is still meaningful (at least don't change the cidr/netmasks). Also provide `nft list ruleset` or if not installed then `iptables-save -c` to also be sure there's really no firewall.